# Tornado Data Points: Linking 2 Points in QGIS on the Same Row

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv, line, qgis-2

So I've got these [tornado .csv files](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/data/2012_torn.csv) that have two latitude & longitude entries with the left-most in the table being the beginning point and the right-most being the ending point of the tornado, as is described [here](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/SPC_severe_database_description.pdf). I'm wondering, how can I link these two points in QGIS, so I get a line?

Comment: How might you represent change in direction over time? There are multiple .csv files for quite a few years back. What technique might you suggest to capture this temporal change in tornado patterns?

Comment: Once you have figured out the answer to your first question, it is better to ask the 2nd & 3rd questions (in your comment) as separate questions.

Answer (score 7):

The simple way to do this, without writing any Python, would be to translate the start and end to a WKT version of the line:

1. Open the csv in Excel or Open Office, or whatever you use
2. Create a new column with the formula:

   `="LINESTRING(" & A1 & " " & B1 & "," & C1 & " " & D1 & ")"`

   *Replacing A1, etc, with your start and end points.*
3. That should give you something like this:

   [image]
4. Save the file and open it in QGIS using the Add Delimited Text File

   [image]

   **Note: If you tick Watch file any time the file changes the map will auto update.**
5. Magic!

   [image]

Comment: that's brilliant! The best part is that one can generalize this approach to create all sorts of interesting geometry from a csv file via WKT. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed one can.  And in the next version of QGIS you will just be able to copy and paste WKT into QGIS (no attributes yet)